# Is there any way for Pandas' read_csv C engine to ignore or replace Unicode parsing errors?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, unicode

Most questions around reading strings from disk in Python involve codec issues. In contrast, I have a CSV file that just flat out has garbage data in it. Here's how to create an example:

```
b = bytearray(b'a,b,c\n1,2,qwe\n10,-20,asdf')
b[10] = 0xff
b[11] = 0xff
with open('foo.csv', 'wb') as fid:
    fid.write(b)
```

Note that the second row, third column has two bytes, `0xFF`, which don't represent any encoding, just a small amount of garbage data.

When I try to read this with [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv') # fails
```

I get an error, naturally:

```
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 881, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  ...
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1520, in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I can however successfully read this file if I use Pandas' Python CSV engine:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('foo.csv', engine='python') # success
```

In this case, the invalid characters are replaced with `U+EFBF` characters that Unicode uses to represent "Invalid Character"s.

**Question:** is there any way for Pandas' C CSV engine to do the same thing as Python's here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The replacement of invalid characters you see with the python engine corresponds to the `errors='replace'` mode when encoding a bytes-like object.

You may read the csv using an arbitrary single-byte encoding and transcode columns with this error mode (passing a converter to `read_csv` or using `series.str.encode/decode` methods) but it's quite cumbersome since you have to identify a specific set of columns.

For a global effect, since `read_csv` does not support (yet) the `errors` parameter, you can pre-open the file with the python built-in `open`, which does support it.

```
df = pd.read_csv(open('foo.csv', errors='replace'))
```

Comment: To other potential readers: please note that the workaround here is appropriate only for *ill-formed utf-8 data*, which is quite *rare* in my experience. In most cases, a decoding error does not mean that the input file is corrupted but that it uses an encoding different than utf-8, the default one. Then the right solution to not lose information is to identify the source encoding and use the `encoding` parameter (or transcode the file beforehand) to properly read it, instead of shutting errors down.